Neo4jError: db.memory.transaction.total.max threshold reached on AWS EC2 instance
I'm encountering an issue with my Neo4j database deployed on an AWS EC2 r6i.2xlarge (8 vCPU, 64GB of RAM) instance. Whenever I execute a specific Cypher query through my Node.js server using the neo4j-driver library (version 4.4.5), I receive the following error:
Neo4jError: The allocation of an extra 2.0 MiB would use more than the limit 56.0 GiB. Currently using 56.0 GiB. db.memory.transaction.total.max threshold reached

Here are some details about my setup:
Neo4j: Community Edition (version: 5.19.0)
Deployment: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-lxxbmpqvwo5eq?sr=0-2&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa#pdp-pricing (used as a template)
Configurations in neo4j.conf:
server.memory.heap.initial_size=56g
server.memory.heap.max_size=57g
server.memory.pagecache.size=2g
db.memory.transaction.total.max=56g
db.memory.transaction.max=56g
dbms.memory.transaction.total.max=56g
server.jvm.additional=-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

Database Schema
Dao {
    organizationId: String!
    daoId: String!
    name: String!
}

Proposal {
    proposalNativeId: String!
    proposer: String!
    (Proposal)-[:IN]->(Dao)
}

Vote {
    voteNativeId: String!
    voter: String!
    choice: String!
    (Vote)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(Proposal)
}

Indexes:
Dao - daoId column
Proposal - proposalNativeId column
Vote - voteNativeId column

Data Volume:
Dao - 1
Proposal - 62
Vote - 483

Problematic Query:
MATCH (d:Dao { daoId: '9ad9fb81-ad04-4830-85c2-212034072580' })<-[:IN]-(v1:Vote)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p:Proposal)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v2:Vote WHERE v1.voter < v2.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v3:Vote WHERE v2.voter < v3.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v4:Vote WHERE v3.voter < v4.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v5:Vote WHERE v4.voter < v5.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v6:Vote WHERE v5.voter < v6.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v7:Vote WHERE v6.voter < v7.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v8:Vote WHERE v7.voter < v8.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
    WITH v1.voter AS member1, v2.voter AS member2, v3.voter AS member3, v4.voter AS member4, v5.voter AS member5, v6.voter AS member6, v7.voter AS member7, v8.voter AS member8, COUNT(distinct p) as voted_on_same_proposal
  
MATCH (d:Dao { daoId: '9ad9fb81-ad04-4830-85c2-212034072580' })<-[:IN]-(v1:Vote)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p:Proposal)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v2:Vote WHERE v1.voter < v2.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v3:Vote WHERE v2.voter < v3.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v4:Vote WHERE v3.voter < v4.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v5:Vote WHERE v4.voter < v5.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v6:Vote WHERE v5.voter < v6.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v7:Vote WHERE v6.voter < v7.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (d)<-[:IN]-(v8:Vote WHERE v7.voter < v8.voter)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
WHERE v1.voter = member1 AND v2.voter = member2 AND v3.voter = member3 AND v4.voter = member4 AND v5.voter = member5 AND v6.voter = member6 AND v7.voter = member7 AND v8.voter = member8
 AND v1.choice = v2.choice AND v2.choice = v3.choice AND v3.choice = v4.choice AND v4.choice = v5.choice AND v5.choice = v6.choice AND v6.choice = v7.choice AND v7.choice = v8.choice
    RETURN [v1.voter, v2.voter, v3.voter, v4.voter, v5.voter, v6.voter, v7.voter, v8.voter] AS members, COUNT(distinct p) AS voted_together, collect(distinct p.proposalNativeId) AS proposal_native_ids, voted_on_same_proposal
ORDER BY voted_together DESC, voted_on_same_proposal DESC
LIMIT 20

The query retrieves information about voters who voted together on the same proposals (with consideration of choice and without) within a DAO.
The goal: get ## number people coalitions for ## number of votes.
I've already increased memory configurations in neo4j.conf as mentioned above and increased the EC2 instance (from r6i.xlarge to r6i.2xlarge), but the issue persists.
Also, is it possible to get logs to understand the progress percentage of the query being performed?
Any insights into resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Not sure about your use case, but this query may get you started in right direction:
MATCH (d:Dao { daoId: '9ad9fb81-ad04-4830-85c2-212034072580' })<-[:IN]-(v0:Vote)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p:Proposal)
WITH p, COLLECT(v0) AS p_voters, COUNT(v0) AS voted_on_same_proposal
ORDER BY voted_on_same_proposal DESC
LIMIT 20 
UNWIND p_voters AS v
RETURN p.proposalNativeId AS proposalNativeId, voted_on_same_proposal, v.choice AS choice, COLLECT(v) AS members_with_same_choice
ORDER BY voted_on_same_proposal DESC, SIZE(members_with_same_choice) DESC
LIMIT 20

This query does not lookup the same patterns multiple times, or order voters by their IDs, and seems to use aggregation more reasonably.
It looks for the 20  most-voted-on proposals for the specified Dao and collects their voters. Then it collects the voters who made the same choice for those proposals, and returns the top 20 results ordered by voted_on_same_proposal and SIZE(members_with_same_choice).

Hi, thank you for this. I tried it and it couldn't make what I needed.
I need to find groups of people who vote together on the same proposals and who vote on the same proposals with the same choice, for all proposals, not for each proposal individually.
